# Bluetooth paired, not connected, sending but not receiving files

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

My PC is running Ubuntu 14.04. I can send files from my PC to my phone. But not the other way. In the bluetooth settings window there is a connection switch that is in the off position. Is this the problem? If so, or if not so, how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Click the Ubuntu icon on the screen and search for Personal File Sharing and enable Receive bluetooth files in Download folder and you should be able to receive bluetooth files
[image: Personal File Share image]

Comment: what about if the screen above is not enabled ? What packages should i install ? i mean first section share files over network

Comment: Package should be `gnome-user-share` and should be able to be found in the software center

Comment: strange it is already installed but even so it is not enabled in the above screen , but if use mouse right button and choose properties it is possible to share folders over network

Comment: You should just have to click next to "Receive files in Downloads folder over Bluetooth" to get it to work